# Bundle install error: sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I have an error that looks like this when I bundle install.

[image]

I've followed the error message and have tried to delete cache my directory:

```
/Users/drubio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/cache/bundler/git/activeadminc24fcef949b2f1bbdf6b5a17650dcd86d73f2528
```

When I try to bundle install I receive the same error again and again with no luck. From what I understand this is a bash script error. However, I didn't create a bash script so when I see the error:

```
sh: -c: line0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

I have no idea what it is referring to.

I've looked at these similar errors on stack overflow

[Cron error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468733/unexpected-eof-while-looking-for-matching)

[Linux Perl Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372779/unexpected-eof-while-looking-for-matching)

[Linux rsync command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272241/unexpected-eof-while-looking-for-matching)

Has anyone experienced this error before? I am not familiar with the internals of bundler or with bash scripts but if I can get a lead to go on that would be great. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I had to run `bundle update activeadmin` to make it work.

Comment: Looks like a bug in bundler. This happened when specifying a github repo in Gemfile. This solution worked.